# refresh parent window when closing child window

Tags: javascript

How can I refresh the parent window when clicking the close button of a child window?

The child window is a pop-up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access the parent window using

```
window.opener
```

and refresh the parent window using

```
window.opener.reload()
```

See **[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)**

Comment: do not forget to check if the opener exists and is still open before trying to refresh it (bulletproofing)  ie if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) { window.opener.reload(); }

Comment: It seems that window.opener no longer has a reload method, but window.opener.location does.

Answer (score 12):

To refresh the parent page on close of child window use the following javascript in the popup page and call that using onunload in the popup page.

```
function refreshParent() 
{
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
}

<body onunload="javascript:refreshParent()">
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<body onunload="window.opener.reload();">
```

If you use this when you close your child window, the parent will be reloaded.
window.opener refers to the parent window object.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
self.opener.location.reload();
```