# Post Back not occuring after pdf is downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I've developed a pdf file using itextsharp.

Pdf generation is working fine. After the pdf is created it's being downloaded.

My problem is when the user clicks on Generate PDF button , Pdf is generated and downloaded properly but postback doesn't occurs.

I want the postback to be occured because I want to Reset my Form after Pdf is generated that is Clear All Fields .

How Can I do this ?

Here is my code :

Method to Generate PDF :

```
  public void GetPDF(string quote_num)
    {
        string url = FilesPath.Path_SaveFile + Session["empcd"].ToString() +"-Quotation.pdf";
        Document disclaimer = new Document(PageSize.A4, 2, 2, 10, 10);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(disclaimer, new FileStream(url, FileMode.Create));
        writer.PageEvent = new myPDFpgHandler(quote_num);
        disclaimer.SetMargins(70, 10, 60, 80);    
        disclaimer.Open();
        GenerateQuotPDF getpdf = new GenerateQuotPDF();
        disclaimer = getpdf.GetPDFparams(disclaimer,quote_num, Session["empcd"].ToString(),txt_contactperson.Text,txt_contact1.Text,txt_company.Text,txt_address.Text,ddl_gene_desc.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_canopy.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_gene_type.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_rentalamount.Text,txt_hours.Text,txt_variable.Text,ddl_terms.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_remarks.Text,txt_technical.Text,ddl_sign1.SelectedValue,ddl_sign2.SelectedValue,txt_designation.Text,DateTime.Now);
        disclaimer.Close();

        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(url);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(url);
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Session["empcd"].ToString() + "-Quotation.pdf");
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Generate PDF Button Code :

```
 protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidQuotation())
        {
            string newQuotNum = rental_quotations.GetNewQuotNumber();
            rental_quotations.AddNewQuotation(newQuotNum, Session["empcd"].ToString(), ddl_gene_type.SelectedValue.ToString(), ddl_gene_desc.SelectedValue, ddl_canopy.SelectedValue, txt_company.Text, txt_address.Text, txt_contactperson.Text, txt_designation.Text, txt_contact1.Text, txt_contact2.Text, txt_rentalamount.Text, ddl_terms.SelectedValue, txt_hours.Text, txt_variable.Text, txt_remarks.Text,ddl_sign1.SelectedValue,ddl_sign2.SelectedValue,txt_technical.Text);
            GetPDF(newQuotNum);
            ClearAllFields();     //this is not working   

        }
    }
```

Comment: it is happening. else your pdf wouldnt be generated

Comment: How Can i resolve this

Comment: in witch technology you are working (web form or mvc )

Comment: @NazirUllah I am working on Webforms

Comment: have you used update panel in your aspx page ?

Comment: @navnit here the postback is not occuring , update panel will have the same problem

Comment: put try and catch block in your code in both method and debug and see. is there any exception thrown ?

Comment: @navnit there is no any exception , it is a very known issue you can google it

Comment: simple reload the page after pdf code is completed with   Response.Redirect( HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

Comment: @NazirUllah it's not working

Comment: where you put this line of code??

Answer (score 1):

Postback is occurring since the file is being created. Try the given solution. Your `GetPDF(string quote_num)` function is doing two tasks that you should break into two functions.

1. Creating the `pdf` document.
2. Downloading the `pdf` file after it is done.

Now, After you have created the document, you should clear the controls and then send the file as response. Therefore do it as follows:

**Create `pdf` file.**

```
public void CreatePDF(string quote_num)
{
    string url = FilesPath.Path_SaveFile + Session["empcd"].ToString() +"-Quotation.pdf";
    Document disclaimer = new Document(PageSize.A4, 2, 2, 10, 10);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(disclaimer, new FileStream(url, FileMode.Create));
    writer.PageEvent = new myPDFpgHandler(quote_num);
    disclaimer.SetMargins(70, 10, 60, 80);    
    disclaimer.Open();
    GenerateQuotPDF getpdf = new GenerateQuotPDF();
    disclaimer = getpdf.GetPDFparams(disclaimer,quote_num, Session["empcd"].ToString(),txt_contactperson.Text,txt_contact1.Text,txt_company.Text,txt_address.Text,ddl_gene_desc.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_canopy.SelectedItem.ToString(),ddl_gene_type.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_rentalamount.Text,txt_hours.Text,txt_variable.Text,ddl_terms.SelectedItem.ToString(),txt_remarks.Text,txt_technical.Text,ddl_sign1.SelectedValue,ddl_sign2.SelectedValue,txt_designation.Text,DateTime.Now);
    disclaimer.Close();
}
```

**Reset the controls.**

```
ClearAllFields();
```

**Send the file as response.**

```
public void SendPDF(string url)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(url);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(url);
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Session["empcd"].ToString() + "-Quotation.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Note that I also added `Response.End()` to clear the buffer.

Comment: still same problem :(

Comment: All the answers **and your question** assume that PDF is similar to HTML. It isn't. If you want the PDF fields to be empty, you need to trigger the "reset" functionality in the JavaScript stored in the PDF. Whether or not that will work, depends on the viewer used by the end user. Since you can't predict that, that solution may be insufficient. Another solution would be to create a new PDF file with empty fields and send that to the end user. However, some viewers (e.g. Adobe Reader) cache field values. I'd drop your requirement if I were you and I'd open the PDF outside the browser.

Comment: Note that I up-voted this answer because @AlinaAnjum broke the rules: you are not allowed to post the same question twice on StackOverflow. I up-voted this answer so that I could close [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983221).