# Is it possible to reload a page in a parent window using javascript from a child window?

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.Net page with a table. The user can click on a button that opens a child window (using JavaScript), and in that new window, he is able to delete records from a database.  The parent window should update a visible array of dots when he does that because those dots depend on the contents of the database.

So I tried assigning the parent window a name (with window.name="myParent" and then passing that via a query-string to the child window.

The child window would call myParent.location.reload(true) when it was finished with the deletions.

This does not seem to work unless I am missing some bug.

Should it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [refresh parent window when closing child window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301278/refresh-parent-window-when-closing-child-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) as a reference to the parent window.

```
// inside parent.html
window.open('./child.html');

// inside child.html
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Comment: Notice, that you can do this only once. When the parent is reloaded, the original reference to `opener` will be gone.