# Angular - Refreshing of parent window when popup window is close

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way in angular typescript on catching the close event of a popup window then refreshing the parent window?

What I have tried is adding this script to the component that will be going to load on to the popup window but it doesn't trigger that event.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
    console.log("foo");
    window.opener.reload();
    window.close();
  }
```

Comment: check `window.postMessage`.

Comment: I assume the popup redirects to some other application, right? Just asking, because you could use modals if it were part of your own application.

Comment: @gyohza yes, you're correct, the popup loads another application and it loads back to my application. Is there any right approach to do this?

Comment: @Mr_Green where should I put window.postMessage to the popup window or to the component where the popup window is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out. So what I am trying to do here is open a popup window to load a different application and it will redirect it back to my application once it is successfully validated.

So, on my application where I trigger the opening of popup window. Here's the code:

```
this.popup = window.open(loginUrl, 'self', 'width=1000,height=1000');
```

and on the other component where the redirection will happen.

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

It is somehow related to this: [refresh parent window when closing child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301278/refresh-parent-window-when-closing-child-window)

Comment: It is better to manage such communications with `window.postMessage`. Check this once https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Hi, @Mr_Green I'll try to read on that one. Thank you very much.